# Incorrect syntax near '=' near WHILE LOOP

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, while-loop

I've wirtten below script, but when i try to execute it give below err -

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6 Incorrect syntax near '='.

```
declare @PostDate date
declare @PostID int
DECLARE @count INT
DECLARE @updatecounter INT

WHILE exists (select top 1 @PostDate = postdate from dateTemp order by postdate desc)

BEGIN

PRINT @PostDate
SELECT @count = COUNT(*) from cs_posts_bkup20160209 where CONVERT(date,Postdate) = @PostDate
print @COUNT
SET @updatecounter = 1

   WHILE (@count>=1)

       BEGIN
    select top 1 @PostID = PostId from cs_posts_bkup20160209 where CONVERT(date,Postdate) = @PostDate and Postorder IS NULL order by postdate desc
    pRINT @POSTID
    --update cs_posts_bkup20160209 set PostOrder = @updatecounter where postid= @PostID
    SET @updatecounter = @updatecounter + 1 
    SET @count = @count - 1
    Print @updatecounter
    Print @count
      END

DELETE from dateTemp where Postdate = @PostDate
END
GO
```

what i am missing here...

please help!!

Comment: You should give like WHILE exists (select top 1 1 from dateTemp where @PostDate = postdate  order by postdate desc)

Comment: You cannot do an assignment inside an EXISTS check. Besides, I think the WHILE approach is not the way to go. SQL operates on sets of data, so you can do the update in a single query.

Answer (score 1):

If you assign a variable in a select, the select will not also return a result set - and a result set is required for `EXISTS`.

Easiest fix is probably to re-run the query that sets `@PostDate` inside your loop and remove the assignment from the query used by the while loop.